# How to create a dropdown that is open by default and with custom scrollbars ( see pic from wireframes) in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web page from the mocks given to me by a graphic designer. I have the following control in the mocks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d39l.jpg

Is there any jquery/css plugin that I could use to create this type of control ? I need to have the dropdown open by default and scrollbars customized. How should I approach this?

Comment: To clarify... when the user selects an item does the control automatically minimize? or does it always show multiple options?

Comment: It always shows multiple options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change how many options are displayed on a select element with the size attribute. You can also use CSS to change the style of the scrollbars.

I'm sure there's probably a library that provides it as some kind of widget. But I wanted to point out that what you're asking for could be done with relative ease without one.

Comment: I used the size attrribute already . I had trouble with scrollbars. I used webkit style data to customize it